# How to rename the Datatable after Deserialize the Json to Datatable using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

```
DataTable dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(JsonData);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

After this  my json data is converted to DataTable as expected, But how to change the name of the datatable (Table1 to "myname") in dataset.

[image]

Comment: You can use [`TableName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename(v=vs.110).aspx) proerty of a `DataTable` to get or set name of `DataTable`. For example `dt.TableName= "SomeTable";`

Comment: I tried this DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.TableName = "somename";
                 dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(input); but still the table is not changing. @RezaAghaei

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of `DataTable`, the method returns an instance. Then you can set the name of `DataTable`.

Comment: Tq..That worked for me.@RezaAghaei